# What is the difference between Speak UI and Sheer UI?

Tags: content-editor

We are switching from Speak UI to Sheer UI due to performance issue. We would like to know what are the screens which would change for an Author in Sitecore CMS

Comment: How are you going to do that? if you do it this way:  https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/359871  the  I assume only the experience editor changes.  but are you sure you cannot fix your performance problem in any other way?

Comment: I am not looking for how it is done but looking for how UI/Functionalities will change for an author. What is the difference UI point of view?

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you on @JitendraGhanekar?